# Check if InitialContext exist before NoInitialContextException occures

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am getting `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException` from Hibernate's `SessionFactory.buildSessionFactory()` method. This is because I am trying to run a testcase outside of container.
 
I have code in place to refer to local Datasource configured in `applicationContext.xml`. Problem is that I am not figure out where to implement local datasource code.
I can not put it inside a `catch(NoInitialContextException)` because SessionFactory class is deep in the code and as per the application design, throwing all exceptions not catching them.

Is there anyway to find out if `InitialContext` exist before hitting the `buildSessionFactory` method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you perform a lookup on the `InitialContext` to check if there is a `SessionFactory`, as described here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/hibernate.html

```
try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    ctx.lookup("java:/hibernate/SessionFactory");
catch (NamingException e) {
    //here you can assume that buildSessionFactory won't work
    ...
}
```